# Change Qt Creator project name for CMake projects

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I've imported CMake project into Qt Creator. However, its name has been set to '**Project**. I can't find GUI entry to change this name to other more meaningful.
I've changed all Project entries in CMakeLists.txt.user file (created by Qt Created). In result - Qt Creator during startup finds modified file faulty and triggers again 'Import project' procedure.
How can I change project name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it adding `project(your_name)` (or changing it if it already exists) at the top of the file `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory of the project itself.
Then open the project and run cmake from within QtCreator.
It will open the project with the right name in the project panel.